# Understanding some of the c++ code

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm having a hard time with the below codes. Please have a look at it, and kindly explain which I'm unable to understand. And please suggest the title of the question if its inappropriate. Thank you.

```
class matrix
{
    private:
        int m,n;
        int mat[10][10];
    public:
        void read_matrix();
        void show_matrix();
        matrix operator + (matrix mt);
};

matrix matrix::operator + (matrix mt)
{
    matrix msum;
    for(int i=0; i<m;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            msum.mat[i][j]=mat[i][j]+mt.mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    return msum;
}

void matrix::show_matrix()
{
    for(int i=0;i<m;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            cout<<setw(8)<<mat[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

- What's happening in this line:

`matrix matrix::operator + (matrix mt)`

- And in this line, what is the value of just the `mat[i][j]` in the middle:

`msum.mat[i][j]=mat[i][j]+mt.mat[i][j];`

- Why is it that, some of the member functions are defined outside the class?

Answer (score 0):

`::` is scope operator . if we define the definition of method outside class, we use this operator to define that this method belong to this class.In this line : `matrix matrix::operator + (matrix mt)` 1st matrix is return type and 2nd is the name of class which it belongs to and `+` sign indicate , we are overloading plus operator to perform some custom plus operation.i.e we can not directly add matrix. but user will try to add two matrix simply by putting + between them. so here we overload + operator so whenever user put + between matrix class object it adds both matrix(i.e 2 dimensional array)

value of `mat[i][j]` will be picked at runtime from what you give it as input. that is 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

- First question: you're overloading + operator. Many operators in c++ can be overloaded. If you write

  int i = 4 + 5;

c++ does know what + operator means, but when you write

```
Matrix mat1 = mat2 + mat3;
```

c++ does not know it, because + does not handle by default Matrix class, because it's not a predefined type.

In Matrix class you can specify what + operator must do with the class, so you can use the + operator instead of something like

Matrix mat1 = mat2.sum(mat3);

- Second Question: i and j are Matrix indices. You use the loop in order to assign temporary value to this variable. You can read it as "for every i value from 0 to m, for every j value from 0 to n, sum values". In this case you can sum every element of the Matrix.
- Third question: becuse usually that's the way. In order to define a class, you put class declaration in a .h file, and definition in a .cpp file, with some exception, like inlined methods. Using this approach user can include .h file and use the class interface without know and modify nothing about it.